# We roll two dice. Let the random variable X be the difference between larger and smaller number of dots

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, dice

We roll two dice. Let the random variable $X$ be the difference between
larger and smaller number of dots.
What's the probability scheme for the random variable $X.$

Comment: What have you done on this so far?

Comment: There are no 'dices' in English. Mouse/mice :: Die/dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe don't look for fancy combinatorial methods here. Instead, just write the sample space as:

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 
21 22 23 24 25 26
31 32 33 34 35 36
41 42 43 44 45 46
51 52 53 54 55 56
51 62 63 64 65 66
```

Then write 36 (absolute) differences in a similar array, and count.

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  2  3  4
2  1  0  1  2  3
...
```

A simulation of many rolls of a pair of dice produced the histogram below
showing a good approximation to the distribution of absolute differences $Y.$
[Each 'brick' in the histogram has area $1/36.]$

[image]

Comment: How about if i were to calculate the mean?

Comment: This works better if you study your text and class notes before trying to work the problems. Just use the definition of the expected value of a random variable: If $p_i = P(X = i),$ for $i = 0, \dots 5,$ Then $E(X) = 0p_0 + 1p_1 + 2p_2 + \cdots + 5p_5.$ Guessing from the balance point of the histogram, somewhere between 1.9 and 2.0. Find the six probabilities $p_i$ and try it.

Comment: With D the difference, we can write $P(D = d) = \frac{6 - D}{36} 2^{I[D > 0]}, d = 0,1,...,5$